# Illegal characters in path while reading json string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am working on reading a json sting in my C# code and run into the error ***"Illegal characters in path"***. I did a check on the json string if it adheres to the standards and no issue there. But, when I try to read this data in my code inexplicably run into this error. I'm using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=net-6.0) to process my json string.

**JSON:**

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Jason1",
        "LastName": "Test1",
        "Email": "123@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Jason2",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Email": "234@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    }
]
```

**C#:**

```
string jstring = @"[{
        "Id": 1,
        "FirstName": "Jason1",
        "LastName": "Test1",
        "Email": "123@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "FirstName": "Jason2",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Email": "234@automail.com",
        "Eligible": true,
        "InsertLogtime": "2022-02-21T00:51:59.917",
        "Comment": null
    }
]";
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(jstring))
        {
           
        }
```

***Error:***

[image]

Comment: please show the code thats reading the JSON

Comment: In your screenshot the path you are using is `jstring`.  I think this is what is causing the issue.  DOCS: `path  String   The file to be opened for reading.`

Comment: File.OpenRead expects a file name, not a json string

Comment: @pm100, I'm posting just the snippet. I am passing the name of the file in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with parsing json

`File.OpenRead` expects a file name. You have passed in a json string, this is not a valid file name, hence the error

You should parse the string directly

Answer (score 0):

you can just parse your json string

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jArray=JArray.Parse(jstring);

var firstName= (string) jArray[0]["FirstName"];
```